# why is cross section of pair production in field of electron smaller than that in the field of nucleus?

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, nuclear-physics

Pair production cannot take place in a vaccum since momentum conservation would be violated. However it can take place in the field of a nucleus or an atomic electron. Why, though, is the cross section for pair production lower for the process happening in the field of electron?

Comment: The questions in your title and your text are opposites. Please edit to make them consistent.

Comment: Do you know size of electron? It can be millions of meter cube to point size of zero, depending on how you detect and define it. Pair size , it's same like for electron. Although standard model considers them point size which you may say is zero.

Comment: @Lewis Miller thankyou for pointing that out, got it corrected.

Comment: @SabeekaNazeer: If CountTo10's previous answer was useful to you you should mark that as accepted, even upvote it. It is the expected _repayment_ for free quality Internet expertise!

Comment: @rodrigo Thank You for suggesting that! iam new to stack exchange and didn't know of this.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect (but haven't looked closely) that it's the charge *density* that matters.  If that were the case, pair production in hydrogen would proceed equally from the proton charges and the electron charges, while pair production in heavy metals comes mostly from the nuclear electric fields.